# Tkinter program not responding in while loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I found some other question about this subject but I didn't understand any of them.

I am trying to make a program which sends a message every x minutes but because of the time.sleep in the loop the program isn't responding anymore.
I tried multi-threading but it doesn't seems to work. I also found root.after but I think that I can't use this inside a while loop.

Anyway here is my code:
(auto-bump means sending !d bump message in discord)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from time import sleep
import re
import urllib.request
import json
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from tkinter import simpledialog
import threading
from queue import Queue


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://discord.com/')
driver = browser


# open file
file = open('settings.txt')
all_lines = file.readlines()


def login(emailInput, passwordInput):
    file = open('settings.txt')
    if emailInput == "":
        emailInput = (all_lines[1])
        emailInput = emailInput.replace("\n", "")
    else:
        pass
    if passwordInput == "":
        passwordInput = (all_lines[3])
        passwordInput = passwordInput.replace("\n", "")
    else:
        pass #  If email and password not in entrys => replace by settings.txt credentials else replace settings credentials by entrys
    print(f"Logging in ...({emailInput}:{passwordInput})")
    try: 
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div/header[1]/nav/ul[2]/li[4]/a').click()
        browser.find_element_by_name('email').send_keys(emailInput) # EMAIL
        browser.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(passwordInput)# PASSWORD
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/input').send_keys(Keys.ENTER) # CONNNECT
    except:
        print("Error while logging in.\nPlease retry or login manually")


def automsg(cldown):
    if cldown == "":
        cldown = (all_lines[5])
        cldown = cldown.replace("\n", "")
        cldown = int(cldown)
    else:
        pass
    message = (all_lines[7])
    print(message)
    cldown = int(cldown)
    cldown = (cldown * 60)
    while True:
        try:
            chatentry = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".slateTextArea-1Mkdgw")
            chatentry.send_keys(message)
            chatentry.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            print("Message sent successfully !")
        except:
            print("Message failed, trying again ...\n")
            sleep(5)
        print(f"Next message in {cldown} secondes")
        sleep(cldown)


def autobump(cldown):
    if cldown == "":
        cldown = (all_lines[5])
        cldown = cldown.replace("\n", "")
        cldown = int(cldown)
    else:
        pass
    print(cldown)
    cldown = int(cldown)
    cldown = (cldown * 60)
    while True:
        try:
            chatentry = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".slateTextArea-1Mkdgw")
            chatentry.send_keys("!d bump")
            chatentry.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            print("Bumped successfully !")
        except:
            print("Bumped failed, trying again ...\n")
            sleep(5)
        print(f"Next bump in {cldown} secondes")
        sleep(cldown)

def help():
    webbrowser.open('https://pastebin.com/5Vx5qxxx', new=2)



# Looks settings


HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 500


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Discord Assistant (by Sarlay#3151)")
root.minsize(width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
root.maxsize(width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
root.iconbitmap("icon.ico")


canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()


background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"./bg.gif")
background_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)


SettingsFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
SettingsFrame.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.05)

SettingsFrame2 = tk.Frame(root, bg="#24b8b8")
SettingsFrame2.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.15, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.05)


emailEntry = tk.Entry(SettingsFrame2, font=8)
emailEntry.place(relx=0.02, rely=0.15, relwidth=0.35, relheight=0.8)

emaillabel = tk.Label(SettingsFrame, font=40, text="email")
emaillabel.place(relx=0.15, rely=0.2)

passwordEntry = tk.Entry(SettingsFrame2, font=8)
passwordEntry.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.15, relwidth=0.25, relheight=0.8)

passwordlabel = tk.Label(SettingsFrame, font=40, text="password")
passwordlabel.place(relx=0.44, rely=0.2)

cooldownEntry = tk.Entry(SettingsFrame2, font=8)
cooldownEntry.place(relx=0.67, rely=0.15, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.8)

cooldownlabel = tk.Label(SettingsFrame, font=8, text="cooldown(min)")
cooldownlabel.place(relx=0.69, rely=0.2)

LoginButton = tk.Button(root, text="Login", font=40, command=lambda: login(emailEntry.get(), passwordEntry.get()))
LoginButton.place(relx=0.46, rely=0.3)

AutoMsgButton = tk.Button(root, text="Auto-message", font=40, command=lambda: automsg(cooldownEntry.get()))
AutoMsgButton.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.4)


HelpButton = tk.Button(root, text="?", font=40, command=help)
HelpButton.place(relx=0.95, rely=0.03)


AutobumpButton = tk.Button(root, text="Auto-Bump", font=40, command=lambda: autobump(cooldownEntry.get()))
AutobumpButton.place(relx=0.42, rely=0.5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Event handler function needs to finish quickly, since until it complete, no other GUI events can be processed. Both sleep and an infinite loop are a big no-no there. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632/tkinter-how-to-use-after-method on how you can have things happen periodically without blocking the event loop.

Comment: You need to use the universal [`after()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222214221id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method not `time.sleep()` to introduce delays in tkinter apps and prevent them from "hanging" because its `mainloop()` is being interfered-with.

Answer (score -2):

Multithreading seems a bit overkill for this problem. You could try something like this.

```
import time
send_message()
last_message = time.time() 
while:
    do_stuff()
    if time.time()-last_message > 60*x:  # time.time() - last_message gives the difference in seconds between now and when the last message was send.
        send_new_message()
        last_message = time.time()
```

Comment: Not applicable to a tkinter-based app.